# Any way to transfer clipboard between machines on the network?

Tags: remote, clipboard

Working with remote computers (using remote desktop or so) one can usually just transfer clipboard contents between those computer. But say i got 2 computers connected to one monitor via a KVM switch, is there a easy way to transfer clipboards between those?

Is there something like *remote clipboard* solution? Multiplatform solution would be cool, but something working in Windows is most interesting

**edit:**
I do not want to get rid of KVM, as I need to work on each computer on a physical monitor but still not need a bunch of monitors. A remote desktop solution is therefor not an option. I just want the clipboard part.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you could use the KVM to switch monitors and plus the keyboard and mouse into one of the machines. Then install synergy on all of the machines connected to the KVM.

Comment: Then I have to move around mouse between screens I can not see. Not very optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) has a clipboard synchronization mode, although I have never tried how well that works. It's windows only and can only transfer images and text, but I use it even on a single PC due to its clipboard history.

Comment: The setup is not too obvious, but after some tinkering it works, and works well.

Comment: How to setup this on Linux?

Answer (score 4):

I hear [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) lets you do that. From what I read it works on Mac, Windows, and Unix. The only problem with this solution is that each computer would need it's own monitor, but it would let you get rid of the kvm.

You could also just use the kvm to switch monitors and not plug in the keyboard/mouse.

Comment: Clipboard sharing is certainly one feature of Synergy, but I'd question whether just that part of Synergy could be used meaningfully without multiple screens.

Comment: Good edit, that's better ;-)

Comment: Synergy+ is a new fork of the original Synergy. http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/

Comment: oh cool.. I loved synergy , then it was not free anymore.. actually for just windows to windows Input Director is the best, but synergy was good for disparate systems

Answer (score 2):

[Synergy+ shares your clipboard](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/) - it allows you to copy text from one screen, then move your mouse to another screen, and and simply paste. Your clipboard is shared between all your computers over the network.

Answer (score 0):

[**Build a Shared Clipboard Utility in Python**](http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/37233/1763) discusses how to do this with Python.
Unfortunately, there is no full-solution download around,
but I thought, this could be useful for some enthusiast project.

> Here's a quick scenario that illustrates the basics. Suppose you're running both a Mac and a Windows machine. You select and copy the text "The shared clipboard is awesome!" from within a text editor on the Mac (see Figure 1). Having done that, you can now paste that exact same text into an application on a separate Windows machine (see Figure 2). The shared clipboard works in the background, making clipboard interactions between machines as simple as copying and pasting between applications on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get ditto to talk over multiple routers.

So, I tried [Clipboard Share](https://clipboardshare.codeplex.com/), which worked well. It does its job and that good: It allows to send the current content of the clipboard to another PC running Clipboard Share. No history, ...

Another alternative is [Clipboardic](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/clipboardic.html), which saves each clipboard content to a `clp` file, which allows more reuse than ditto.

More software is listed at http://alternativeto.net/software/clipboard-share/.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the same network and all of your computers are running Windows, then you should try Mouse Without Borders. This application allows you to move your mouse between computers like you would if you had a dual monitor setup. The nice thing here is that copy and paste works well between all computers. You can easily move your mouse on monitor A, copy something and then move your mouse or of the screen to the other monitor of computer B and paste.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460